# Raspi2 Win 10 IOT C# + MySql

Tags: mysql, windows, arm

Is it possible to run a C# project that connects to MySql DB with Raspi2 + Win10 IOT.

Which driver for MySql can connect should I use, since it is an ARM  CPU.

Thanks for help

Švigo

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows 10 IoT is a thing right now here a later answer:

MySQL and MSSQL Connections are not available with UWP (includes WinIoT + RaspberryPi)
I recommend you pass Data via Socket Communication:

[ClientCode: How to Connect](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/StreamSocket/cs/Scenario2_Connect.xaml.cs)
(Sending Strings in other Scenario)

[Server: Listener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In general it is an asynchron Connection so take care you use proper Callback.